# How to only grep one of each address. Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

Okay so lets say I have a list of addresses in a text file like this:

```
https://www.amazon.com
https://www.google.com
https://www.msn.com
https://www.google.com
https://www.netflix.com
https://www.amazon.com
...
```

There is a whole bunch of other stuff there but basically the issue I am having is that after running this:

`grep "https://" addresses.txt | cut -d"/" -f3`

I get amazon.com and google.com twice. I want to only get them once. I don't know how to make the search only grep for things that are unique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pipe your output to sort and uniq:

```
grep "https://" addresses.txt | cut -d"/" -f3 | sort | uniq
```

Comment: Wow I did not know there was a way to do that. I guess I don't know how to use google very well... Thanks a lot man, I'll accept your answer as soon as the system lets me

Answer (score 3):

you can use `sort` for this purpose.

just add another pipe to your command and use the unique feature of sort to remove duplicates.

```
     grep 'https://' addresses.txt | cut -d"/" -f3 | sort -u
```

EDIT: you can use `sed` instead of `grep` and `cut` which would reduce your command to

```
    sed -n 's@https://\([^/]*\).*@\1@p' < addresses.txt | sort -u
```

Answer (score 1):

`grep "https://" addresses.txt | cut -d"/" -f3 | sort | uniq` is what you want

Answer (score 1):

I would filter the results *post-grep*.

e.g. using `sort -u` to sort and then produce a set of unique entries.

You can also use `uniq` for this, but the input has to be sorted in advance.

This is the beauty of being able to pipe these utilities together. Rather than have a single grepping/sorting/uniq(ing) tool, you get the distinct executables, and you can chain them together how you wish.

Answer (score 1):

with awk you can use only one unix command instead of four with 3 pipes:

`awk 'BEGIN {FS="://"}; { myfilter = match($1,/https/); if (myfilter) loggeddomains[$2]=0} END {for (mydomains in loggeddomains) {print mydomains}}' addresses.txt`